# Installing Symfony,Composer

Tags: macos, symfony, composer-php

Just to see if anyone can help me out, i'm sure its very very basic but I've only just flipped to mac from windows and learning the terminal basics

I am trying to install and use Symfony, i have installed homebrew, then i put in the composer command-

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

it downloads and installs but then it says i the path/ directory is not valid/ now i understand i need to make it, but i'm not sure where this will lie, and what is the command to make a director? is it mkdir -- ?

heres the terminal log-

```
Calvins-MacBook-Pro:~ calvin$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

Composer successfully installed to: /Users/calvin/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
Calvins-MacBook-Pro:~ calvin$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
mv: rename composer.phar to /usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory
Calvins-MacBook-Pro:~ calvin$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx

> Note: In OSX Yosemite the /usr directory does not exist by default. If
>   you receive the error "/usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or
>   directory" then you must create /usr/local/bin/ manually before
>   proceeding.

To create an directory you need to execute:

```
sudo mkdir <path>
```

Comment: Ahhhhh okays that makes more sense ill give that a try, thank you!